# Generating a dictionary based on a condition among columns of a dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have the following df:

```
                        before         actual
AC                      12.120         340.65
BA                      7.382          158.45
AA                      42.140         200.55
AD                      18.340         650.00
AT                      76.100          1.00
```

I would like to iterate over the rows in this df and check that if any of the values in `df["actual"]` is less than the values from `df["before"]` , generates a dictionary with key the index and values the `df["before"]` value and the `df["actual"]` value.

This is what I have tried:

```
dictionary_gobal={}
for index, row in df:
    if df["before"]<df[actual]:
        rdo_nocumple={index:[row["before"],row["actual"]}


        print(rdo_nocumple)
```

however it outputs the error:

```
 ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Desired output:

```
{"AT":["76.100","1.00"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need first filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), then transpose and convert to [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
d = df[df["before"] > df['actual']].T.to_dict('list')

print (d)
{'AT': [76.1, 1.0]}
```

If want also values convert to `string`s:

```
d = df[df["before"] > df['actual']].astype(str).T.to_dict('list')
print (d)
{'AT': ['76.1', '1.0']}
```

Detail:

```
print (df[df["before"] > df['actual']])
    before  actual
AT    76.1     1.0
```